# Handle exceptions without crashing socket server?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, exception, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to run a threaded socket server that handles multiple clients simultaneously. However after I telnet into the server and then exit in a non-graceful way, say by closing the window.

The server crashes and returns `System.out.println("Runnable terminating with exception: " + e );` with `e` being `java.Lang.NullPointerException`.

**My question is how can I simply close the socket and keep the server running even if something goes wrong in `handleSession()`, so that others can connect?**

I am new to exceptions so my understand is still elementary.

```
publc class ThreadedHandler implements Runnable {
    Socket incoming;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    SortedTopicList topics;

    ThreadedHandler(Socket s) {
        incoming = s;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            handleSession(incoming);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Runnable terminating with exception: " + e );
        }
        }

    public void handleSession(Socket client) {
        try {
            //Code goes here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            shutdown();
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            incoming.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My main method is as follows:

```
public class MessageBoardServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t;
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(118118);
            while(true) {
                Socket session = ss.accept();
                t = new Thread(new ThreadedHandler(session));
                t.start();
            }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Comment: What? Server socket on `118118`? It works?

Comment: Where is your BufferedReader and PrinteWriter initialized?  Have you posted all the code?

Comment: They are intialised in `//Code goes here`.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your server crashes? I have just tested your code by throwing a NullPointerException in handleSession() and it just prints the message and continues. I can connect again and it prints that again. Your main thread looks too simple to crash for no reason. By the way, you should use e.printStackTrace() for debugging purposes as it gives you much more information than e.getMessage().

Comment: I just retested the code and it appears to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Executor, to create thread pool, and delegate thread executing to that pool.
Even if one thread throws an exception, the others will be still active.
You can add "unhandledExceptionHandler" to Executor, where you can log every exceptions.

First [Executor usage example](http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/11/java-5-executors-threadpool.html) from google

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to put `while` body inside a try/catch block, since any error there breaks the loop.

About the NPE - seems that you initialize `BufferedReader in;`, `PrintWriter out;` inside the `handleSession` method, in `try`. If something fails before is has initialized `in` and/or `out`, it will fail with NPE, since `shutdown` called in finally and closes `in` and `out`.

The code as it posted here doesn't break the main loop around `accept` on NPE in the `run` of the handler thread.

Comment: I assume you mean to wrap the `while` loop that in the `ThreadHandler` class? Also where should I intialise the `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter`? It doesn't work in `run()` either.